# Springboot is not throwing the error to the client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want that when an error is encountered, the user receives in the exception response to his http call.
The error is indeed caught, displayed in the spring logs, but it is not returned to the user.
Why ?

My method :

```
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) {
    try {
      // Check for authorization header existence.
      String header = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_STRING);
      if (header == null || !header.startsWith(JwtConstant.TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
      }
      // Validate request..
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authorization = authorizeRequest(request);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authorization);
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      throw new InternalServerErrorException("Erreur sur le filtre interne -> " + e.toString());  // Should return this to the user
    }
  }
```

The error in logs :

```
.common.application.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Erreur sur le filtre interne -> 
.common.application.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Erreur lors du authorizeRequest
```

The error Handler :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    String typeDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
...

    @ExceptionHandler(InternalServerErrorException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleInternalServerErrorException(InternalServerErrorException ex,
            WebRequest request) {

        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(
                new SimpleDateFormat(typeDateFormat).format(new Date()), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false), "500");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

InternalServerErrorException.java

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class InternalServerErrorException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InternalServerErrorException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    }

}
```

ExceptionResponse.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionResponse {
    
  private String date;
  private String message;
  private String uri;
  private String status;
  
}
```

The user receive a 403.. i don't know why, but should receive the error that i throw, without any body..

The InternalServerException works outside of the try/catch..

Answer (score 1):

Basically `@ControllerAdvice` will only work if the exception is thrown from the `@Controller` / `@RestContoller` method.

Technically , the `spring-mvc` framework stuff (i.e `@ControllerAdvice`) will only take effect for an HTTP request if it can be successfully passed through all the `Filter` in the `SecurityFilterChain` (configured by spring-security) and processed by the `DispatcherServlet`. But now it seems that your exception is thrown from one of the `Filter` in the `SecurityFilterChain`
before the request reach to `DispatcherServlet` , and hence `@ControllerAdvice` will not be invoked to handle this exception.

You have to consult about if there are related configuration in that spring-security filter that allow you to customize the exception. If not , you can still manually do it in that filter since you can access `HttpServletResponse` from there.

Comment: Yes i can access the servelet response, but doing this : 
} catch (Exception e) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      response.sendError(500, e.getMessage());
      return;
    }

is not throwing the error back to client